# Powerapps Canvas Apps gallery with multiple combobox filters

Tags: powerapps-canvas

I am trying to add filter in gallery view where the filters are in  4 combobox so how to write a query for the gallery view filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter([table], ('comboboxname'.Selected.'filedname' = 'filedname' || 'comboboxname'.Selected.'filedname' = 'filedname')

this is the way I've set the filter of one gallery that is filtered by two combobox combined

this "Filter" must be put in the "Items" of the gallery

Lorenzo

Comment: can i get data onclick of button when i select values in filter for gallery to diaplay the combobox values